# How to install custom rom on completely broken screen

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode, twrp, usb-debugging, broken-screen

So I have a samsung S7 with a broken screen. It's completely black and no longer responsive. I've been using scrypy to control the device. It has twrp installed and its rooted. However, I want to install a custom rom on device (I play games on it using keyboard and there's a game I want to download but it requires android 10 but samsung s7 stops at android 8) but obviously there going to be a problem here because twrp requires touch plus I cant even see anything, Also, scrypy doesnt work in recovery mode. Is there a way I can do a blind install of a custom rom and also re-root the phone if I lose root access. Keep in mind that the device has black screen and the touch no longer works so even if I manage to get a guide on how to do it, I still need scrypy to use the device on boot after installation cause the phone would've been wiped by then thereby resetting the usb debbuging setting (I's assuming this will be the case). Any guide on how to do this?

Comment: For flashing you could use Odin/Heimdall on a connected PC, so you would not need the phone display. And there are customROMs with pre-enabled adb. However there is still a significant risk to "brick" the phone (get the phone into a state where you would need the display to understand and solve the problem).

Comment: you can see something in TWRP: make screenshots and pull them.. TWRP also has a bunch of adb commands https://twrp.me/faq/openrecoveryscript.html install LineageOS that comes with adb enabled